# not all the sub interfaces under the bridge get the packets

Tags: linux, networking, interface, bridge

I have bridge that have two interfaces
My bridge name is **brServer**
My two interfaces name is **vnet104 & vnet60**

when I send traffic to the bridge **just vnet104 get the traffic** and **vnet60 get just get some ARP's**
when I make vnet104 down so vnet60 start to get traffic

is there any option to make the **both interfaces vnet104 and vnet60 get the same traffic??**

Comment: That is correct. Bridges learn which interfaces are connected to which MAC addresses, and they only forward frames to the interface where the destination MAC address is connected. Only broadcasts and unknown unicasts are flooded to all bridge interfaces. That is why bridges have MAC address tables, and it is the function of a bridge.

Comment: thanks Ron for your replay,
I see the MAC address table for my bridge I was wondering if I can to make any change to forward all the traffic to all the interfaces.
I will tell you that this issue happened just when I in routing mode
is there a way to resolve it??

Comment: The MAC address table builds automatically every time a frame enters the bridge. The entries will eventually time out if no frame is received during the time period. You seem to want the equivalent of a hub, not a bridge. You may also be able to create a mirror, but I do not know about that bridge capability. The point of a bridge is to limit where frames are sent, but you want to break that.

Comment: thanks Ron,
but why this is happened just in routing mode? 
is there a way to forward packets through any tool I mean from interface to interface